# could not exec dpkg! e: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100) - I cant fix it

Tags: dpkg

I have tried installing PHPMyAdmin via terminal by using the next command: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`, the results of the terminal are as shown:

```
> root@ns382469:~# apt-get install phpmyadmin Leyendo lista de
> paquetes... Hecho Creando árbol de dependencias Leyendo la información
> de estado... Hecho Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes extras:  
> dbconfig-common libltdl7 libmcrypt4 php5-mcrypt Paquetes sugeridos:  
> libmcrypt-dev mcrypt www-browser Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes
> NUEVOS:   dbconfig-common libltdl7 libmcrypt4 php5-mcrypt phpmyadmin 0
> actualizados, 5 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
> Necesito descargar 6.441 kB de archivos. Se utilizarán 17,5 MB de
> espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación. ¿Desea continuar
> [S/n]? S Des:1 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main
> libltdl7 amd64 2.4.2-1.1 [352 kB] Des:2
> http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main libmcrypt4 amd64
> 2.5.8-3.1 [83,2 kB] Des:3 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main dbconfig-common all 1.8.47+nmu1 [487 kB] Des:4
> http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main php5-mcrypt amd64
> 5.4.39-0+deb7u2 [16,1 kB] Des:5 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ wheezy/main phpmyadmin all 4:3.4.11.1-2+deb7u1 [5.503 kB] Descargados
> 6.441 kB en 0seg. (8.520 kB/s) Preconfigurando paquetes ... Could not exec dpkg!

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Note: My system is set to Spanish Language.

When I try to install somethink I have this same error when running the `sudo apt-get install` command.

### Edit

After following Geppettvs D'Constanzo advice on permissions on dpkg I receive this in the terminal:

```
Root@ns382469: ~ * chmod 755/usr/bin/dpkg
chmod: it is not possible to accede to "/usr/bin/dpkg": the file or the directory does not exist
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you do before you got that error msg?

Comment: sudo apt-get install

Comment: Post the entire command you ran and the entire output. The small part you posted is too generic

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DG4S5CAY

Answer (score -1):

A quick search on several support places returned many posts talking about dpkg permissions which is solved by providing the proper permissions as mentioned in this site: https://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/debian-apt-get-installs-fail-with-dpkg-error-code-100/

I am going to reproduce the steps over here for your convenience.

> The Advanced Package Tool, or ‘apt’ on Debian-based systems is the
>   mainstay for installing, upgrading and removing packages.  Behind the
>   various apt tools, the Debian package manager, dpkg, carries out the
>   heavy lifting.  You might wish to install new versions of packages
>   periodically with the sequence:
>
> ```
> apt-get update
> apt-get upgrade
> ```
>
> Recently, this and any other upgrade failed on Debian Lenny with:
>
> ```
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
> ```
>
> A quick look at /usr/bin/dpkg revealed the following!
>
> ```
> ---------- 1 root root 365324 2010-03-08 15:35 dpkg
> ```
>
> A quick ‘chmod 755 /usr/bin/dpkg’ fixed the problem!  I know I did not
>   change the permissions, so it must have been a recent patch. 
>   Hopefully this gets fixed quickly!

I suggest you to have a look (as mentioned in the page) to dpkg permissions in order to see if this is your case. You can do it by running `ls -l /usr/bin/dpkg`

It should return something like:

```
geppettvs@T400:~$ ls -l /usr/bi/dpkg                                          
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 261840 jun  9  2014 /usr/bin/dpkg
```

Please edit your question in order to add the details of this last command and if you see different file permissions, try the solution previously mentioned in order to attempt fixing your error.

If you need further help don't hesitate to drop a comment over here.

Good luck!

Comment: it dosen´t work;                                                          http://pastebin.com/Lkn4VtcY

Comment: Where I can download the / usr / bin / dpkg ?

Comment: I edited your question in order to add the details on pastebin. For future references please edit the question on your own in order to include the details. For your dpkg missing, please check this thread at Ubuntu Forums which seems to have at least two advices on how to fix it. http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-197819.html Good luck!