# how can I fix dpkg error code(100)

Tags: 16.04, dpkg

I can't install any package even `dpkg` my `dpkg` file's and folders has been deleted and I received this error:

```
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

**EDIT:**
When I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg`
I got this output:

```
dpkg: warning: 'dpkg-deb' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

### EDIT

When install buddgie desktop

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 budgie-desktop-environment : Depends: budgie-lightdm-theme (>= 0.5.4) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: plymouth-themes but it is not installable
                          Recommends: arc-firefox-theme but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: pocillo-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: budgie-indicator-applet but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: vertex-theme but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: gthumb but it is not installable
                          Recommends: rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar but it is not installable
                          Recommends: menulibre but it is not installable
                          Recommends: transmission but it is not installable
                          Recommends: tlp but it is not installable
                          Recommends: budgie-welcome but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Seen https://askubuntu.com/q/603968/367990 already?

Comment: add the command you used to de package the file

Answer (score 2):

You might want to reinstall dpkg by doing the following:

```
sudo -i
mkdir /tmp/dpkg

cd /tmp/dpkg
```

*Mind that you might want to look whether the download links are still up-too-date*

**If you are running a 32 bit version of ubuntu**

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_i386.deb
```

**For 64 bit**

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb
```

then

```
ar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz

tar xfvz data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
```

Now copy the binary to `/usr/bin` with

```
sudo cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin
```

And finally run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61453/discussion-on-answer-by-addb-how-can-i-fix-dpkg-error-code100).

Comment: meen come to chat room